# onchange event does not trigger on Multiselect picklist in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, multi-select

Goal is: Based on Multiselect Picklist value selection/deselection, I want to hide/show certain text area fields on my LWC form.

**Below is my LWC:**

**HTML:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Custom_Object__c">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Multiselect_Picklist__c" value={multiselectPickVal} onchange={handleMultiPickChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class createRecordForm extends LightningElement {
   handleMultiPickChange(event) {
   console.log('Calling handleMultiPickChange:'+event.detail.value);
       this.multiselectPickVal = event.detail.value;
   }
}
```

when I Select value in MultiSelect Picklist, event handleMultiPickChange is not getting called.

Is there any limitation for Multiselect picklist? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling LWC on Process Flow and while debugging process flows, I have observed that it does not trigger an event such as onchange,Navigation. I have checked for other data types and behavior is same.

After adding Process flow on Custom Action, It's working on Record Page.